# What is the difference in the logic of the below functions?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out what exactly is causing these functions to have different behavior. The logic seems exactly the same.

I tried debugging and what it seems to me is that in the second example the addition is adding to two rows at once.

```py
def uniquePaths(self, m: int, n: int) -> int:
    grid = [[1]*m] + [[0]*(m)]*(n-1)
    for row in range(1, n):
        for col in range(m):
            if col - 1 < 0:
                grid[row][col] = grid[row-1][col]
            else:
                grid[row][col] = grid[row-1][col] + grid[row][col-1]
    return grid[-1][-1]
```

```py
def uniquePaths2(self, m: int, n: int) -> int:
    grid = [[1]*m] + [[0]*(m)]*(n-1)
    for row in range(1, n):
        for col in range(m):
            if col - 1 >= 0:
                grid[row][col]=grid[row][col-1]
            grid[row][col] += grid[row-1][col]
    return grid[-1][-1]
```

Comment: In the 2nd one you are appending into the grid and in first you are just assigning.

Comment: You should add that as an answer, @RamanMishra

Comment: @RamanMishra I don't think thats the case. when you index into a grid you get the value out, not an array.

Comment: But the values will be different? Don’t you think so??

Comment: Raman appears to be correct. In the first one, if col < 1, you are **setting** current cell to the same as the one from the above row. If current cell was 5 and row above (same col) was 10, current cell becomes 10. In the second one, if col < 1, you are **adding** current cell and the cell from above row. That means, current cell will become 15.

Comment: @zedfoxus the current cell should be 0 as per the initialization right? adding shouldn't make a difference if we start from 0. We also only touch each cell once so this can't change.

Comment: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] is a sample matrix that we are working with here if you plug in inputs 7, 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the way I initialized the matrix messed with how the code performed.

```
grid = [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
for col in range(m):
    grid[0][col] = 1
```

The logic in the if statements was correct.
Somehow the other initialization caused every element per column in the matrix to update.

It appears that python makes a copy of the list when you multiply them such that the following behavior is possible:

```
>>> grid = [[1]*m] +[[0]*(m)]*(n-1)
>>> grid
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> grid[1][0] = 5
>>> grid
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Notice that the 5 gets updated in both rows.

Answer (score 0):

There seems a logic flaw in your code, may be your functionality needs. Below is the explanation for both:
Code 1:

```
if col - 1 < 0:
    grid[row][col] = grid[row-1][col]
else:
    grid[row][col] = grid[row-1][col] + grid[row][col-1]   
    # Above line adds grid[row-1][col] and grid[row][col-1], and assigns to grid[row][col]
```

Code 2:

```
if col - 1 >= 0:
    grid[row][col]=grid[row][col-1]
grid[row][col] += grid[row-1][col]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if col - 1 >= 0:
    grid[row][col] = grid[row][col-1]            # assigning some value to this cell
    grid[row][col] = grid[row][col] + grid[row-1][col] # overwriting that cell
    # grid[row][col] = grid[row][col-1] + grid[row-1][col] # above two lines are equivalent to this
else:
    grid[row][col] = grid[row][col] + grid[row-1][col]
```

Hope, you get the difference, and can modify codes as per your requirements.

Comment: as your post clearly explains there is no logic flaw in the code.

Comment: He is using code 1 and code 2 as hit and trial method, which has completely different meaning. Isn't this a logic flaw? I have also added that, if it's your requirement, then it's okay.